# Quotient by a finite group of fixed-point-free isometries

Tags: group-theory, quotient-spaces

I'm reading one paper in Riemannian manifolds which very briefly mentions that quotients of $S^{2}\times R^{1}$ by a finite group of fixed point free isometries include $S^{2}\times S^{1}$, $RP^{2}\times S^{1}$. I know what are fixed points of isometries, but I searched for more information on how to find such quotients and in vain. I found no information going more deeply in explaining that finite group of fixed point free isometries or how to find such kinds of quotiens. 
Textbooks, papers that eplain and deal with those things would be very appreciated.

Comment: You probably want to look at papers on $3$-manifolds. These quotients should be precisely the $3$-manifolds with Thurston geometry (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrization_conjecture#The_geometry_of_S2_.C3.97_R) $S^2 \times \mathbb{R}$ and these are classified, and probably you can find the classification somewhere if you use those keywords.

Comment: Peter Scott's article on 3-dimensional geometries is an excellent source. One more manifold you are missing is a nontrivial circle bundle over projective plane. That's all.

Comment: Thanks for clarifications!